# Debugging Memory Leaks in Windows Component Object Model (COM)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, com

We have a native C++ application running on Windows which uses Component Object Model (COM)  as a client.  In our case, we can using `IUIAutomation`.  Unfortunately, we have memory leaks in our code that aren't showing up using our basic memory debugging approaches:

`_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

How can we debug memory leaks in our executable related to our misuse of COM/IUnknown/and memory allocations across the COM barrier?

We are flexible on tools/libraries/etc.  We are on Windows 8 running Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Time has not been kind to the tool vendors.  Nevertheless, these leaks should show up in standard tooling [like umdh.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` will only detect leaks on your heap, not on the heap of the COM server unless you can recompile the latter.

Comment: IMallocSpy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688508(v=vs.85).aspx also seems to be a possibility.

Comment: I found this very usefull: http://comcorba.tripod.com/comleaks.htm

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with [BSTR caching](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/09/28/hey-why-am-i-leaking-all-my-bstrs/).

> Basically, OLE caches all BSTR objects allocated in a process to allow it to pool together strings.  As a result, these strings are effectively leaked "on purpose".  The KB article indicates that the cache is cleared when the OLEAUT32.DLL's DLL_PROCESS_DETACH logic is run, which is good to know, but didn't help me to debug my BSTR leak – I could still be leaking BSTRs.

The good thing is that you can [disable this caching](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139071) by setting the environment variable `OANOCACHE=1` and rebooting. Or you can call [SetOaNoCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644360) within your program without affecting your whole operating system.